# How can I expand a string variable but escape any special characters within

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

let's say I have an array of strings that have been pulled in from a CSV file and the contents of the troublesome strings look something like this:

```
PS C:\> $line.theString
This string` has 'funky'?/ "characters" that I'd like to escape
```

How can I get to the string while escaping the contents of the string?
I've tried the following:

```
$page.ListItem["theString"] = $line.theString
$page.ListItem["theString"] = @'$line.theString'@
$page.ListItem["theString"] = $line.theString
$page.ListItem["theString"] = ${line.theString}
$page.ListItem["theString"] = "[regex]::escape($line.theString)"
$page.ListItem["theString"] = "[uri]::EscapeDataString($line.theString)"
$page.ListItem["theString"] = "System.Management.Automation.WildcardPattern]::Escape($line.theString)"
```

If the text contains:
     `Bachelor's degree or equivalent in a related subject.`
When saved to the page, my result looks like:
`Bachelor�s degree or equivalent in a related subject.` (The � looks like a square in the browser)
Could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where are these strings coming from? Are they stored in a text file; entered in the script directly; someplace else?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the desired result would be. Please provide an example.

Comment: You may also try `[uri]::EscapeDataString()`, `[System.Management.Automation.WildcardPattern]::Escape()`, and something else. And you may define the specs, so that we can give an answer.

Comment: What you have wouldn't be valid anyway since you have single quotes to create the string then unescaped single quotes within the string. So I'm pretty sure this isn't exactly how your code really is.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  The strings are pulled from a CSV and stored in an array of objects

Comment: It sounds like an encoding issue to me.

Comment: @grizzljt - You say you are saving to a page and viewing in a browser; are you trying to output HTML? If so, does `[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlEncode()` work?

Comment: @grizzljt - There should not be quotes around the method calls (e.g. `$page.ListItem["theString"] = "[regex]::escape($line.theString)"` should be `$page.ListItem["theString"] = [regex]::escape($line.theString)`)

Comment: I also find this question very unclear. You're not providing much context. How are **$line** and **$page** being defined? (i.e. post the ***code*** you use to create them.) What do you mean by "save to the page"? Where exactly are you seeing the � characters? For example, are you creating a web page and viewing it in a browser? Please be clear things like that rather than leaving them to inference. How about providing some sample input and sample output?

Comment: Anyway, I agree with @EBGreen that this looks more like an encoding issue than an escaping issue. Are you sure the `'` is an ordinary apostrophe (straight quote) and not a similar character?